# ActiveModelSerializers isn't used for render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am using version `0.9.3` of Active Model Serializers. When I call `render json: @collection` or even an individual object it uses the default `to_json` method and returns the full object. Im not trying anything fancy. My controllers are in the directory `app/controllers/v1/` and the serializers are in the directory `app/serializers/v1/` and I have also tried them in `app/serializers/`. The serializer class name is `UserSerializer` and the model is `User`.  Any ideas why this may be happening would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a collection of objects, specify the `each_serializer` when you render:

```
  render(
    json: @collection,
    each_serializer: UserSerializer
  )
```

If it's a single object, then specify the `serializer`:

```
  render(
    json: @user,
    serializer: UserSerializer
  )
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and it doesn't work. I get the error on the collection that it can't find a template. So it is searching for the views/jbuilder files.

Comment: Did you specify `each_serializer` using their namespaced name?

Comment: Passing `serializer:` for a single object works but the collection still is looking for the view associated with the `index` method. For the `each_serializer` I am passing in the `V1::UserSerializer` with no luck

Comment: If the single object works with `serializer` option, then the collection of objects should work with `each_serializer ` option!

Comment: I can't figure out why it is searching the app for a view still

Comment: This is very unlikely, but just for trying, can you specify `root` option as well? `root: :users` and see what happens

Comment: `root: :users` didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88607/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-cwitty).